# Site-wide filter (module), best practises?

Tags: filter

I'm making a redesign for a website that sells bespoke versions of 12 insurance products to 12 different types of businesses, supplemented with information also specific to the type of business. The old site currently has a separate page for each business and their associated products, so a lot of pages.

The problem: It's possible for one company to encompass multiple types of businesses, leading to them having to view 3 separate pages about essentially the same product just because the business activities overlaps. This lead to a lot of confusion (understandably) because people got confused about which product fit their situation and which they had to request.

To counter this, we want to make a site-wide filter that allows people to select their business activities and based on that, we generate only information applicable to their business and situation. We would essentially only have 1 page per product, instead of 12. My question is: Are there any best practises for a site-wide filter? When is it appropriate to ask people for their information (business activities), straight away or contextual based on actions like selecting a product? And which shape fits the purpose the best, full screen or part of the page? Any examples would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you asking about a global navigation categorized by product line?

Comment: Not quite a navigation, more like a filter that uses your input (business activities) to show relevant information and generate insurance products with the specs that matter to you. The navigation itself would be the same for all users, just the content shown on the pages would be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, Insurance is your primary domain. You have multiple products which all cater for that domain.

For your case, I think a wizard guide might be more appropriate. You may want to guide the visitor to the appropriate product by asking a series of questions. After a limited set of questions, users will reach to the appropriate product.

On that page, you can have sections of related product and other products. These sections will take you to other places on the same site.

You might find the following approaches useful.

- [BankBazaar's credit card selection tool](https://www.bankbazaar.com/credit-card.html)
- [CarAndBike's Car Recommendation tool](http://www.carandbike.com/research/recommend-cars)

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question right, which i don't think i have, This below is what you want:

[image]

Comment: Not quite what I meant, but thank you for your input. I'm going to brainstorm a bit more to see if I can make this idea more coherent.